# Javascript == and === comparison

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I am testing something in Javascript and when comparing 2 values in if statement like == or === returning different. Could somebody explain to me difference between these 2 comparisons?

Comment: Look at the second related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/does-it-matter-which-equals-operator-vs-i-use-in-javascript-comparisons?rq=1 in the right of the page

Comment: See `Equal (==)` and `Strict equal (===)` in the table [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators).

Comment: This gives a pretty good description.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/does-it-matter-which-equals-operator-vs-i-use-in-javascript-comparisons